# Browse Button in DataGridTemplateColumn of Datagrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

[image]We have WPF application, In which we use DataGrid on one form.
We have used multiple DataTemplateColumn in that DATAGRID.
I need to take one button in one column, suppose 'BROWSE' button.
Now when I click it in EDIT mode it open file dialog, when I select file, path of that file must get stored in that DATAGRID column.
So how to achieve this, In EDIT mode BRowse button & in Normal Mode Path of that file.

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Attachment Copy Of Invoice" Width="180" >
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="Attach"  Text="{Binding Path=Attachment,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Button Name="Click" Click="Click_Click" ></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

CODE:

```
 private void Click_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension

        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
        if (result == true)
        {

            // Open document

            string filename = dlg.FileName;


        }


    }
```

I need to store filename i.e. path to same TextBlock.

Comment: Show code-behind. "path of that file must get stored in that DATAGRID column" - which column?

Comment: @ Andrey Gordeev: I have added code pls Check it.

Comment: Which column you want to bind filepath to?

Comment: Same Column i.e. <TextBlock x:Name="Attach"  which display Button <Button Name="Click" Click="Click_Click" > in EDIT mode. & after selecting Path It should bind that path to that TextBlock

Comment: It seems it's bound to `Attachment` property. Is it in `ViewModel` or in code-behind?

Comment: I have added IMAGE also, I am not using ViewModel, I want normal C# code to achieve this. From Image you can see that I want path to same position Instead of Button, Path will display in TextBlock.

Comment: Post the complete code. How do you bind the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Currently I am entering value row by row basis.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Click_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Set filter for file extension and default file extension

    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

    // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox
    if (result == true) {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;
        var yourType = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as YourType;
        yourType .Attachment= filename;
    }
 }
```